# Sending json by curl to node.js that will read it

Tags: json, node.js, curl

Could you help me with this one?

I'm sending request type: post, to node.js server:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{'name':'somename','year':'2009'}" http://localhost:3000/achivements
```

In backend server, I'm reading it thru the express:

```
exports.addAchivement = function(req, res) {
   var achivements = req.body;  
   console.log(achivements);
   res.send(achivements);
   (...)
```

Now I want to create JSON object with achivements. So I can acces variables like achivements.name;
The problem is I can't.
achivements = JSON.parse(achivements) is not working
And console.log(achivements) is throwing //"{'name':'someone','year':'2009'}": ""

How can I make JSON object with it, to use it lately?

Regards, and many thanx for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not JSON, it's JSON5. While it has similar syntax, your standard JSON parser won't accept it.

To send a classic json, you need to swap single and double quotes in your request:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name":"somename","year":"2009"}' http://localhost:3000/achivements
```

Comment: I'v used it. JSON.parser still throwing error, console.log(achivements), throws: { '\'{name:somename,year:2009}\'': '' } now

Comment: I guess you didn't change outer double quotes to single ones. I suggest to copy-paste my string exactly as is.

Comment: I did copy and paste your string. :) Hmm, mby problem is that node.js adding \ things. When I'm printing to console req.body, it's showing me { '\'{name:somename,year:2009}\'': '' }, probably JSON.parser doesn't understand that variable.

Comment: well okay, you can try escaping quotes: `curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"name\":\"somename\",\"year\":\"2009\"}" http://localhost:3000/achivements`

Comment: It looks a bit better, { '{"name":"somename","year":"2009"}': '' }, but parser still doesn't like it. Probably because of this : '' at the end :)

Comment: do you have `app.use(express.json())` somewhere in your app?

Comment: yes I do, I have it in main app.js file: app.use(express.json()); When I'm creating json variable inside node.js function: achivements = '{"name":"somename","year":"2009"}'; parser is working, so I think the problem is with reading posted json variable corectly.

Comment: Ok I think it's curl problem, mby parameters construction. I'v posted JSON by HTTP server using AJAX, and node.js automaticaly loaded JSON, i didnt even need to parse it. So now, I/WE :) Just have to work on curl.

Answer (score 0):

just add \" for your key/value pairs in your command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{'\"name'\":'\"somename'\",'\"year'\":'\"2009'\"}" http://localhost:3000/achivements
```